# rails runner not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running: `script/runner -e production MyModel.delay.capture_authorizations`

However, I don't think that it's running. My Model function has `capture_authorizations` defined:

```
def capture_authorizations
  puts 'whatever'
  File.open('/root/lograils', 'a') {|f| f.write("STUFF") }
end
```

That doesn't appear to be doing anything however. When I run the command, it displays nothing and that file isn't written to.

Also, I've `chmod 777`ed the crap out of the `/root/lograils` file, so it's definitely writeable.

Comment: have you tried with Rails.logger?

Comment: Yup.. tried that. Negative

Comment: What is `MyModel.delay`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jim Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719547/jim-stewart) helped with his comment. I took out the `.delay` and everything works smoothly. Thanks!